# SQL query check value exists in lookup based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup-tables

I have Name/Value pair records in a table and I need to confirm the values exist against a lookup for each Name

**KeyVal - Table of NameValue pairs**

```
| MyID1 | MyRecNumber | MyFieldName | MyFieldValue |
|-------|-------------|-------------|--------------|
| 1     | 1           | FirstField  | One          |
| 2     | 1           | SecondField | Car          |
| 3     | 2           | FirstField  | Two          |
| 4     | 2           | SecondField | Firetruck    |
| 5     | 3           | FirstField  | Blue         |
| 6     | 3           | SecondField | Car          |
```

**LookupTable - Table to match Name Values (from KeyVal) with LookupValue (in CheckVals table)**

```
| MyID2 | MyFieldName | LookupName |
|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1     | FirstField  | FieldOne   |
| 2     | SecondField | FieldTwo   |
```

**CheckVals  - Table with valid values for each field**

```
| MyID3 | LookupFieldName | LookupValue |
|-------|-----------------|-------------|
| 1     | FieldOne        | One         |
| 2     | FieldOne        | Two         |
| 3     | FieldOne        | Three       |
| 4     | FieldTwo        | Car         |
| 5     | FieldTwo        | Truck       |
| 6     | FieldTwo        | Bus         |
```

I have a query that will check values against a single name lookup, but am unsure how to make this check all names against the lookup table.  In this query it bypasses the `LookupTable` as I specify the lookup value in the query itself.

```
DECLARE @AttributeName AS  VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Lookup AS  VARCHAR(50)

SET @AttributeName = 'SecondField'
SET @Lookup = 'FieldTwo';

SELECT
    MyRecNumber,
    MyFieldName,
    MyFieldValue
FROM
    dbo.KeyVal kv
WHERE
    MyFieldName = @AttributeName
    AND MyFieldValue NOT IN
        (
            SELECT
                LookupValue
            FROM
                dbo.CheckVals cv
            WHERE cv.LookupFieldName = @Lookup
        )
```

**Question:** How can I do a lookup against **all** values in the `KeyVal` table, through the `LookupTable` table, to check if the value in `MyFieldValue` exists in `CheckVals` against the `MyFieldName` and `LookupName` match?

This is what I'm hoping to get - the two rows that have invalid values are returned in the query results

```
| MyRecNumber | MyFieldName | MyFieldValue |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|
| 2           | SecondField | Firetruck    |
| 3           | FirstField  | Blue         |
```

---

Sample Tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyVal](
    [MyID1] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MyRecNumber] [smallint] NULL,
    [MyFieldName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MyFieldValue] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LookupTable](
    [MyID2] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MyFieldName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LookupName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CheckVals](
    [MyID3] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LookupFieldName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LookupValue] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[KeyVal]
    ([MyRecNumber], [MyFieldName], [MyFieldValue])
VALUES
    (1, 'FirstField', 'One'),
    (1, 'SecondField', 'Car'),
    (2, 'FirstField', 'Two'),
    (2, 'SecondField', 'Firetruck'),
    (3, 'FirstField', 'Blue'),
    (3, 'SecondField', 'Car')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[LookupTable]
    ([MyFieldName], [LookupName])
VALUES
    ('FirstField', 'FieldOne'),
    ('SecondField', 'FieldTwo')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CheckVals]
    ([LookupFieldName], [LookupValue])
VALUES
    ('FieldOne', 'One'),
    ('FieldOne', 'Two'),
    ('FieldOne', 'Three'),
    ('FieldTwo', 'Car'),
    ('FieldTwo', 'Truck'),
    ('FieldTwo', 'Bus')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you want the rows in the first table where the values do not match:

```
select kv.*
from keyval kv left join
     lookuptable lt
     on kv.myfieldname = lt.myfieldname left join
     checkvals cv
     on cv.LookupFieldName = lt.LookupName and
        cv.LookupValue = kv.MyFieldValue
where cv.myid3 is null;
```